# Counting how many times there are blank lists in a list of list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a list:

```
l = [['a', []], ['b', []], ['c', []], ['d', ['e']], ['f', []], ['g', ['h']], ['i', ['j']]]
```

I want to count how many lists have the element [] next to the first element.
for example, in this list we have 4 lists that have a blank list next to its first element.

Another example could be:

```
l2 = [['a', []], ['b', []], ['c', []], ['d', ['e', 'f']], ['g', ['h', 'i']], ['j', ['k', 'l']], ['m', ['n', 'o']]]
```

Here we have 3 lists that have elements that are [] next to the first element of a list.

``````````````
I tried doing something like, but it returns 0
`````````````
def counting(l):
    c = sum(x.count("[]")for x in L)
    return c
``````````````

Comment: ``"[]"`` is just a *string* of an opening and closing bracket. ``[]`` is an empty list. Correcting your typos, ``sum(x.count([]) for x in l)`` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single line solution doing what you want

```
def counting(l):
    return sum(x.count([]) for x in l)
```

Comment: There is no need to re-invent the ``list.count`` method. This is exactly the same behaviour, but slower.

Comment: You are right @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score -2):

Since you require the empty list to be after the first element in each list this would work.  Updated.

```
sum([1 for x in l if x[1]==[]])
```